# Learning technologies that are not required at the workplace

Tags: career-development, skills

I am really interested and I would really like to learn technologies that the company I work for doesn't use and need.

I want to learn C#(already started), MongoDB and serverless, possibly get AWS certified.

The problem is the company I work for just doesn't need them at the moment and learning without practice and building projects is pointless. So I will have to do this in my own time.

My question is how do I proceed? Should I just learn them and never use them professionally or should I look possibly for a different job opportunity?

Comment: What do **you** want to do? That's really the only important part here.

Comment: Well, there was once a case where I practiced React.js in my freetime, and then there was a chance to do a prototype of a system at my work. We went with React mostly because I had already started learning it, and my colleagues had interest in it. Otherwise we would have used jQuery, which was the *de facto* frontend library at the office at that time.

Comment: " never use them professionally" - how do you know? You are a slave or something? Most people in your profession SO change jobs occasionally. Never is a long time.

Comment: @TomTom yes you are right, maybe I am overthinking too much, after all it's all about the passion and what makes us feel good and coding just feels good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is the company I work for just doesn't need them at the moment and learning without practice and building projects is pointless.

This has nothing to do with the company you work for. They hired you to perform a particular job with a particular set of skills. If you want to learn other *things* then that's really just up to you.

> So I will have to do this in my own time.

As do I and everyone else.

What I can tell you is that *most* people **don't**. There are just a *few* people who are passionate about their skills enough to learn more on their own time. Most people will give up if it interferes with their life to much or they don't see a return on their efforts quick enough.

To really learn something it takes years.

> My question is how do I proceed?

**Slowly**.

Each programming language is like a *foreign country*. You can learn to speak the language, but it takes time to understand the culture.

When you talk to other programmers who know that language. They can tell if you are a native or a foreigner.

The best way to proceed is to make new friends who are passionate about those skills. Volunteer to help them with their projects (i.e. open source). Contribute a little bit at a time and be consistent in your efforts (i.e. 10 hours every week).

> Should I just learn them and never use them professionally or should I look possibly for a different job opportunity?

Chicken and egg problem. If you can get a new job for those new skills that is the shortest path to developing those skills (assuming it's a good place to work).

You should also go buy a lottery ticket if that happens.

Ask yourself why you're doing this? What motivates you and are you truly passionate about these technologies?

Live in the now and build things now you love with these new tools. The new job will come later.

Comment: The reason why I want to learn them is purely out of curiosity and because I want be a good employee if sometimes those skills are needed.
Thank you for the perspective, I will make a not of the suggestions.